# Error "Could not create task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'" after adding ksp

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use android room in a kotlin project, so I added **ksp** in the settings, but now I am getting the following error in build:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'.
   > Cannot query the value of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' property 'moduleName' because it has no value available.
```

I have the following settings:

// build.gradle (project):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.21-1.0.11" apply false
}
```

// build.gradle (module):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.prueba.myapplication2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.prueba.myapplication2"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    val room_version = "2.6.1"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

It's a new project, that were working before the addition of ksp,
there are not errors in the log pointing to any code line of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:<PUTVERSIONHERE>")
}
```

to your app-level `build.gradle` file and it should work.

Check out [this documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-quickstart.html#create-a-processor-of-your-own) for more guidance.

Comment: thanks, but that did not solved the problem, but updating the "id("com.google.devtools.ksp")" to 
'id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.21-1.0.15" apply false'
helped